# How can I install Java on a Samsung 3 Chromebook (ChromeOS)?

Tags: java, google-chrome-os, chromebook

There don't appear to be any Apps for this, and from what I've seen Google and Oracle don't look like they're going to be getting along any time soon.

Comment: Java is not supported officially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but be warned, there are negative repercussions by doing so.

Go into Dev Mode and you'll be able to do it, but, for just one example you may lose things like Netflix

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/7L3gg5Fat5o)

Comment: Is this still true